# How to exclude empty tables from Full Joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to grab all the data from temp tables that have different obj types, and I have no idea if a table is empty or not. I use a full join, but it is including the empty table. How do I exclude those? In my example below I want to exclude PURCHASES

Code:

```
select 
    coalesce(tab.name, tab1.name, tab2.name) name, 
    tab1.location location, tab2.eduhist eduhist, tab3.purchases purchases
from 
    tab 
full join 
    tab1 on tab1.name = tab.name
full join 
    tab2 on tab2.name = tab1.name
```

Output:

```
Name(varchar2)  LOCATION(obj1)  EDUHIST(obj2)   PURCHASES(obj3)   
---------------------------------------------------------------
Carol           Some object     NULL            NULL
Desi            Some object     NULL            NULL
Mary            NULL            Some object     NULL
```

Comment: This isn't Jeopardy SQL, also show us the table data giving the above specified result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm OVERcomplicating things, but - I don't see any simple way to do that.

It is kind of unclear what exactly you want to "remove" - is it a column that contains all NULL values, or table from FULL OUTER JOIN?

Whichever of these two it is (or maybe both?), I'd say that you'll need **dynamic SQL**. Read: PL/SQL, possibly a function that returns refcursor.

Why? Because:

- if you want to omit column that has all NULL values, you have to create SELECT statement that doesn't contain that column
- if you want to omit table, you have to fix FROM clause

and none of these can be done in a "static" way.

Therefore, in that PL/SQL piece of code, you'd check whether table - whose name you should know in advance, as well as all column names! - contains any rows when joined to other tables (you should also know in advance). Then compose SELECT statement which is a *source* for refcursor returned by that function.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a query has fixed, pre-determined columns. If you want to exclude a query then you need to use a use a dynamic query.

Alternatively, you can swap from returning columns to returning rows:

```sql
SELECT  tab.name, 
        'location' AS type,
        tab1.location AS value,
FROM    tab
        INNER JOIN tab1
        ON tab1.name = tab.name
UNION ALL
SELECT  tab.name, 
        'eduhist' AS type,
        tab2.eduhist AS value,
FROM    tab
        INNER JOIN tab2
        ON tab2.name = tab.name
UNION ALL
SELECT  tab.name, 
        'purchases' AS type,
        tab3.purchases AS value,
FROM    tab
        INNER JOIN tab3
        ON tab3.name = tab.name
ORDER BY name
```

Then if a table has no data then it will not generate any rows in the output.

If you then want to pivot the output into a dynamic number of columns then do that in whatever third-party language (i.e. C, Java, PHP, Python, etc.) you are using to query the database because that is going to support displaying the output from dynamic pivoting better than SQL.

Comment: I tried using UNION but it doesn't work for my object data types that are different from one table to another. Maybe I'm missing something?